# Flatpickr picks today's date on close when none selected

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

When I open then close the Flatpickr instance without picking a date it sets it to today's one. How to prevent that behavior? I need the date input to stay empty when not set by user.

The Flatpickr instance is wrapped with React-Flatpickr.

```
<Flatpickr
    ref={fpStartDate}
    className='th-input-container__input'
    value={startDate}
    onClose={(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => { 
        if (selectedDates.length > 0) {
            setInputValue(1);
            setCurrentPage(1);
            setStartDate(selectedDates[0]);
        }
    }}
    options={{
        enableTime: true,
        enableSeconds: true,
        dateFormat: 'd.m.Y, H:i:S',
        locale: Russian,
        mode: 'single',
        time_24hr: true,
        minuteIncrement: 1,
        allowInput: true,
        disableMobile: true,
        monthSelectorType: 'dropdown',
        onOpen: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                instance.open();
            }, 200);
        }
    }}
    placeholder='from'
/>
```

Comment: Hi, so what is your solution? It's happen to me too, I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a bug since a certain version. The exact version number could be found in the Flatpickr GitHub issues. The solution I chose was to downgrade.